# Can't start Genymotion

Tags: java, genymotion, nativescript

I'm using Opensuse Tumbleweed, I'm trying to run genymotion without luck.

```
$ ./genymotion
```

And then I get this error:

```
/genymotion: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib64/libX11.so.6: undefined symbol: xcb_wait_for_reply64
```

Answer (score 6):

Open the folder that you extracted the files and remove ***libxcb.so.1***

Comment: This should be a comment instead of a question

Comment: But, i fell that remove these lib file makes genymotion more slow.